# Trim left non ascending elements from array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql-9.3 with an integer array column.
I need to trim the arrays such that I keep elements starting from the end of the array which are ascending.

Example array: `{2,6,8,3,4,5,8,9,11,3,5,7}`

trimmed:
`{3,5,7}`

The code does not need to be fast or pretty, it gets run once to fix some bad data.

Comment: I am left with the **right portion of the array which is ascending** is not clear. Elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

I did not expect to manage, but I did solve it myself:

```
select arr[(select coalesce(max(row_number)+1,1) from (
    select unnest, lead(unnest) over(), row_number() over () from (
        select unnest(arr) from test where id=c.id
    ) as a
) as b where unnest>lead):array_upper(arr,1)] 
from test as c;
```